# Searching for a Text string on a JavaScript web page with PowerShell

Tags: javascript, powershell-3.0

I am trying to search for this string "This update is provided as an Optional update on Windows Update." on this web page "https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3139923" in PowerShell.

I tried rendering and all possible options and I only get the HTML code back.

I believe the page is using JavaScript code and I do not know how to access that text sentence with PowerShell. I have spent hours looking on the internet and have tried everything I know.

Is there anyway to search that page with PowerShell for that Text Line?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: java and javascript are completely different. The page your talking about uses javascript, not java.

Comment: @StephaneM, right, retagged and edited.

Comment: Hi John, Did my answer help you? Do you need a better explanation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the IE com object to do what you need,

```
$url = "https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3139923"

$ie = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application; 
$ie.visible = $false; 
$ie.navigate($url);
While ($ie.Busy)
{Start-Sleep -Seconds 1}

Start-Sleep -Seconds 5; 

$div = $ie.Document.getElementById("mt2")
$HasText = $div.innerText -split "[`r`n]" | select-string "This update is provided as an Optional update on Windows Update" -Quiet

$ie.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($ie)
Remove-Variable ie
```

1. We browse to the page wait for IE to report its loaded
2. Wait additional 5 seconds to make sure the scripts have finished loading
3. We get the DIV that has the data we need.
4. .innerText shows just the text in the div
5. Split the text on line breaks and feed it to `select-string`

Using `-Quiet` returns true if the text is found so `$HasText` will be true if the text is on the page.